# C++ / WinAPI: How do I get a value from a function in the injected x64 DLL?

Tags: c++, winapi, 64-bit, createremotethread

x86 way of doing this is easy and straightforward - through GetExitCodeThread. Unfortunately it's limited to returning 32 bit values. As I understand it WinAPI provides no 64 bit alternative.

So the problem is - I have no trouble calling the injected function by finding its base address through CreateToolhelp32Snapshot module loop then running CreateRemoteThread using it, it does whatever I wrote in it as it should but how exactly do I retrieve its return value without GetExitCodeThread? As an example I want to retrieve a 64bit pointer or even a struct (or a 64bit pointer to one) as a result of this function. What would be a correct way of doing it? And if it's ReadProcessMemory - then which memory address/offset should I read for a return value?

Edit: additional info:
I'm calling a function inside an injected DLL. The function executes some stuff (e.g. collection of data from the process it's injected into, which is successful) - the problem is I want to retrieve one of those variables back into the calling process (the one that calls CreateRemoteThread). GetExitCodeThread is a no go because variables are 64 bit.

code snippet for reference (hExportThread function returns uint64_t in DLL):

```
// LLAddr = LoadLibraryA address, lpBaseAddr = dll path related argument
HANDLE hInjectionThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProc, NULL, NULL, LLAddr, lpBaseAddr, NULL, &idThread);
WaitForSingleObject(hInjectionThread, INFINITE);

dllBaseAddr = getDLLBaseAddr();  // gets base address of the injected DLL
dllExportOffset = getDLLExportOffset(dllExportName.c_str());   // opens the DLL in the local buffer and gets the correct offset
LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE lpNewThread = LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE(dllBaseAddr + dllExportOffset);  // gets the correct address of the function in the injected dll

HANDLE hExportThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProc, NULL, NULL, lpNewThread, NULL, NULL, 0);  // executes injected function
WaitForSingleObject(hExportThread, INFINITE);
```

Comment: It might help if you could write a little bit more about your situation and what problem you're actually trying to solve.  I just figured out that `CreateRemoteThread` creates a thread in *another process* and you're trying to get info out of that process and into your current process.     Maybe you can make a bit of shared memory that is accessible by both processes and pass a pointer to it when you call `CreateRemoteThread`.

Comment: @DavidGrayson the situation is calling a function inside an injected DLL. The function executes some stuff (e.g. collection of data from the process it's injected into, which is successful) - the problem is I want to retrieve one of those variables back into the calling process (the one that calls CreateRemoteThread). GetExitCodeThread is a no go because variables are 64 bit.

Comment: [Sharing files and memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/sharing-files-and-memory) from MSDN.   (I hope you're not building spyware or viruses.)

Comment: @DavidGrayson thank you, shared memory is the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you use a shared memory region, have it open in both the injecting process and the injected DLL. When the injected library finishes you know that the memory should be ready.

Doing this, you aren't limited to 4 or 8 bytes, you can make the region of whatever size is needed to return the collected data.

Comment: OK so my solution to the problem is: gather all the needed data, calculate its size (DWORD is more than enough for storing that value as the data will not be larger than 4GB), report its size through GetExitCodeThread to the main app so it will know what to receive / error checking - and use shared memory to get that data from the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be, rather than asking the remote thread to execute the target DLL function directly, you can have the injector use `VirtualAllocEx()` to allocate a small block of executable memory in the remote process, and then use `WriteProcessMemory()` to fill that block with a *minimum* set of Assembly instructions needed to call the target DLL function and save its result to a memory location where the injector can then access the data from.  That could be a block of shared memory, or a block of `VirtualAllocEx`-ed memory that you read with `ReadProcessMemory()`.

Or, if you are allowed to change the signature of your target DLL function, then have it take a pointer to a local memory address where it can write its output to, and then the injector can `VirtualAllocEx()` a block of read/write memory and pass its address in the `lpParameter` parameter of CreateRemoteThread()`, and then` ReadProcessMemory()` from that address after the thread exits.

Otherwise, rather than setting all of this up manually at the call site where you launch the remote thread, it would be easier if you wrapped the target DLL function in another DLL function that did this work in plain C++ instead of in Assembly.  And then you can have the remote thread call that wrapper function instead.